# Missing type annotation for A. A is a type parameter declared in function type

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-redux, expo, flowtype

I have the following code:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import planeReducer from './plane/reducer';

export default combineReducers({
    planes: planeReducer
});
```

which runs properly when running:

```
> expo start
```

Then, when I run `flow` with the following command:

```
>  npm run flow
```

I get the following flow error:

```
Missing type annotation for A. A is a type parameter declared in function type [1] and was implicitly instantiated at
call of combineReducers [2].

     src/store/index.js
      1| import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
      2| import planeReducer from './plane/reducer';
      3|
 [2]  4| export default combineReducers({
      5|        planes: planeReducer
      6| });
      7|

     flow-typed/npm/redux_v4.x.x.js
 [1] 56|   declare export function combineReducers<O: Object, A>(reducers: O): CombinedReducer<$ObjMap<O, <S>(r: Reducer<S, any>) => S>, A>;
```

Then, when I modify the code above by adding: `<any, any>` as follows:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import planeReducer from './plane/reducer';

export default combineReducers<any, any>({
    planes: planeReducer
});
```

when I run `flow` again as before, the `flow` error goes away, but if I run again:

```
> expo start
```

I get the following runtime error:

```
[01:30:16] Your app is running at exp://192.168.1.194:19000
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
[01:30:16] SyntaxError: D:\react-navigation-header-issue\src\store\index.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (4:34)
[01:30:16]   2 | import planeReducer from './plane/reducer';
[01:30:16]   3 |
[01:30:16] > 4 | export default combineReducers<any, any>({
[01:30:16]     |                                   ^
[01:30:16]   5 |        planes: planeReducer
[01:30:16]   6 | });
[01:30:16]   7 |
```

Any idea on how to modify the code properly in order fix that `flow` error and at the same time keep the applicatioin running with no errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `@flow` pragma comment in the first line of the file. It's probably related to the babel issue: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9240.

**Edit**:
There's [undocumented `all` option in `flow-strip-types`](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9240#issuecomment-464840888) (`babel-preset-expo` makes use of it internally).

You need to overwrite it in your babel config:

```js
overrides: [{
    plugins: [
        ['@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types', {all: true}],
    ]
}]
```